# Grails memory leak - ConcurrentHashMap

Tags: grails, jboss, websphere, grails-2.0

Grails performance & memory leak question -

We have a v2.1.1 Grails 3-tier web application that runs on JDK 6.0 that can be deployed to Jboss 5.1 and WebSphere 8.5.5.4 environment.
We are currently having memory issue, the heap space gets exhausted after hours of Seleninum test runs.
With JavaMelody and YourKit tool, we found one of the big leak suspect is ‘ConcurrentHashMap’ but unable to trace it back to our own code,
and most of the suspects pointing to Grails framework libraries. Any tip?
We are looking for paid service to help us resolve this issue if anyone familiar in this area.

List of Grails plug-in we use. Does any of the listed plug-in you have experienced with memory issue in the past that we should avoid or replace:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module type="JAVA_MODULE" version="4">
  <component name="FacetManager">
    <facet type="web" name="GrailsWeb">
      <configuration>
        <webroots>
          <root url="file://$USER_HOME$/.grails/2.1.1/projects/myApp/plugins/plugin-config-0.1.5/web-app" relative="/" />
          <root url="file://$USER_HOME$/.grails/2.1.1/projects/myApp/plugins/json-rest-api-extended-0.2.6/grails-app/views" relative="/" />
          <root url="file://$USER_HOME$/.grails/2.1.1/projects/myApp/plugins/spring-security-ui-0.2/web-app" relative="/" />
          <root url="file://$USER_HOME$/.grails/2.1.1/projects/myApp/plugins/spring-security-ui-0.2/grails-app/views" relative="/" />
          <root url="file://$USER_HOME$/.grails/2.1.1/projects/myApp/plugins/mail-1.0.1/grails-app/views" relative="/" />
          <root url="file://$USER_HOME$/.grails/2.1.1/projects/myApp/plugins/jquery-1.8.0/web-app" relative="/" />
          <root url="file://$USER_HOME$/.grails/2.1.1/projects/myApp/plugins/famfamfam-1.0.1/web-app" relative="/" />
          <root url="file://$USER_HOME$/.grails/2.1.1/projects/myApp/plugins/jquery-ui-1.8.15/web-app" relative="/" />
        </webroots>
        <sourceRoots />
      </configuration>
    </facet>
    <facet type="hibernate" name="Hibernate">
      <configuration>
        <datasource-map />
        <naming-strategy-map />
      </configuration>
    </facet>
  </component>
  <component name="NewModuleRootManager" inherit-compiler-output="true">
    <exclude-output />
    <content url="file://$USER_HOME$/.grails/2.1.1/projects/myApp/plugins/db-reverse-engineer-0.5">
      <sourceFolder url="file://$USER_HOME$/.grails/2.1.1/projects/myApp/plugins/db-reverse-engineer-0.5/src/java" isTestSource="false" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$USER_HOME$/.grails/2.1.1/projects/myApp/plugins/db-reverse-engineer-0.5/src/groovy" isTestSource="false" />
    </content>
    <content url="file://$USER_HOME$/.grails/2.1.1/projects/myApp/plugins/famfamfam-1.0.1">
      <sourceFolder url="file://$USER_HOME$/.grails/2.1.1/projects/myApp/plugins/famfamfam-1.0.1/grails-app/taglib" isTestSource="false" />
    </content>
    <content url="file://$USER_HOME$/.grails/2.1.1/projects/myApp/plugins/grails-melody-1.58.0">
      <sourceFolder url="file://$USER_HOME$/.grails/2.1.1/projects/myApp/plugins/grails-melody-1.58.0/src/groovy" isTestSource="false" />
    </content>
    <content url="file://$USER_HOME$/.grails/2.1.1/projects/myApp/plugins/hawk-eventing-0.5.1">
      <sourceFolder url="file://$USER_HOME$/.grails/2.1.1/projects/myApp/plugins/hawk-eventing-0.5.1/src/java" isTestSource="false" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$USER_HOME$/.grails/2.1.1/projects/myApp/plugins/hawk-eventing-0.5.1/src/groovy" isTestSource="false" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$USER_HOME$/.grails/2.1.1/projects/myApp/plugins/hawk-eventing-0.5.1/grails-app/i18n" isTestSource="false" />
    </content>
    <content url="file://$USER_HOME$/.grails/2.1.1/projects/myApp/plugins/hibernate-2.1.1">
      <sourceFolder url="file://$USER_HOME$/.grails/2.1.1/projects/myApp/plugins/hibernate-2.1.1/grails-app/i18n" isTestSource="false" />
    </content>
    <content url="file://$USER_HOME$/.grails/2.1.1/projects/myApp/plugins/hibernate-hijacker-0.8.1">
      <sourceFolder url="file://$USER_HOME$/.grails/2.1.1/projects/myApp/plugins/hibernate-hijacker-0.8.1/src/java" isTestSource="false" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$USER_HOME$/.grails/2.1.1/projects/myApp/plugins/hibernate-hijacker-0.8.1/src/groovy" isTestSource="false" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$USER_HOME$/.grails/2.1.1/projects/myApp/plugins/hibernate-hijacker-0.8.1/grails-app/i18n" isTestSource="false" />
    </content>
    <content url="file://$USER_HOME$/.grails/2.1.1/projects/myApp/plugins/jquery-1.8.0">
      <sourceFolder url="file://$USER_HOME$/.grails/2.1.1/projects/myApp/plugins/jquery-1.8.0/src/groovy" isTestSource="false" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$USER_HOME$/.grails/2.1.1/projects/myApp/plugins/jquery-1.8.0/grails-app/i18n" isTestSource="false" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$USER_HOME$/.grails/2.1.1/projects/myApp/plugins/jquery-1.8.0/grails-app/services" isTestSource="false" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$USER_HOME$/.grails/2.1.1/projects/myApp/plugins/jquery-1.8.0/grails-app/taglib" isTestSource="false" />
    </content>
    <content url="file://$USER_HOME$/.grails/2.1.1/projects/myApp/plugins/jquery-ui-1.8.15">
      <sourceFolder url="file://$USER_HOME$/.grails/2.1.1/projects/myApp/plugins/jquery-ui-1.8.15/grails-app/i18n" isTestSource="false" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$USER_HOME$/.grails/2.1.1/projects/myApp/plugins/jquery-ui-1.8.15/grails-app/taglib" isTestSource="false" />
    </content>
    <content url="file://$USER_HOME$/.grails/2.1.1/projects/myApp/plugins/json-rest-api-extended-0.2.6">
      <sourceFolder url="file://$USER_HOME$/.grails/2.1.1/projects/myApp/plugins/json-rest-api-extended-0.2.6/src/groovy" isTestSource="false" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$USER_HOME$/.grails/2.1.1/projects/myApp/plugins/json-rest-api-extended-0.2.6/grails-app/controllers" isTestSource="false" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$USER_HOME$/.grails/2.1.1/projects/myApp/plugins/json-rest-api-extended-0.2.6/grails-app/domain" isTestSource="false" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$USER_HOME$/.grails/2.1.1/projects/myApp/plugins/json-rest-api-extended-0.2.6/grails-app/services" isTestSource="false" />
    </content>
    <content url="file://$USER_HOME$/.grails/2.1.1/projects/myApp/plugins/jxl-0.54">
      <sourceFolder url="file://$USER_HOME$/.grails/2.1.1/projects/myApp/plugins/jxl-0.54/src/groovy" isTestSource="false" />
    </content>
    <content url="file://$USER_HOME$/.grails/2.1.1/projects/myApp/plugins/mail-1.0.1">
      <sourceFolder url="file://$USER_HOME$/.grails/2.1.1/projects/myApp/plugins/mail-1.0.1/src/groovy" isTestSource="false" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$USER_HOME$/.grails/2.1.1/projects/myApp/plugins/mail-1.0.1/grails-app/i18n" isTestSource="false" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$USER_HOME$/.grails/2.1.1/projects/myApp/plugins/mail-1.0.1/grails-app/services" isTestSource="false" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$USER_HOME$/.grails/2.1.1/projects/myApp/plugins/mail-1.0.1/grails-app/taglib" isTestSource="false" />
    </content>
    <content url="file://$USER_HOME$/.grails/2.1.1/projects/myApp/plugins/multi-tenant-single-db-0.8.3">
      <sourceFolder url="file://$USER_HOME$/.grails/2.1.1/projects/myApp/plugins/multi-tenant-single-db-0.8.3/src/java" isTestSource="false" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$USER_HOME$/.grails/2.1.1/projects/myApp/plugins/multi-tenant-single-db-0.8.3/src/groovy" isTestSource="false" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$USER_HOME$/.grails/2.1.1/projects/myApp/plugins/multi-tenant-single-db-0.8.3/grails-app/services" isTestSource="false" />
    </content>
    <content url="file://$USER_HOME$/.grails/2.1.1/projects/myApp/plugins/plugin-config-0.1.5">
      <sourceFolder url="file://$USER_HOME$/.grails/2.1.1/projects/myApp/plugins/plugin-config-0.1.5/src/java" isTestSource="false" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$USER_HOME$/.grails/2.1.1/projects/myApp/plugins/plugin-config-0.1.5/src/groovy" isTestSource="false" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$USER_HOME$/.grails/2.1.1/projects/myApp/plugins/plugin-config-0.1.5/grails-app/i18n" isTestSource="false" />
    </content>
    <content url="file://$USER_HOME$/.grails/2.1.1/projects/myApp/plugins/quartz2-2.1.6.2">
      <sourceFolder url="file://$USER_HOME$/.grails/2.1.1/projects/myApp/plugins/quartz2-2.1.6.2/src/java" isTestSource="false" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$USER_HOME$/.grails/2.1.1/projects/myApp/plugins/quartz2-2.1.6.2/src/groovy" isTestSource="false" />
    </content>
    <content url="file://$USER_HOME$/.grails/2.1.1/projects/myApp/plugins/resources-1.2">
      <sourceFolder url="file://$USER_HOME$/.grails/2.1.1/projects/myApp/plugins/resources-1.2/src/java" isTestSource="false" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$USER_HOME$/.grails/2.1.1/projects/myApp/plugins/resources-1.2/src/groovy" isTestSource="false" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$USER_HOME$/.grails/2.1.1/projects/myApp/plugins/resources-1.2/grails-app/i18n" isTestSource="false" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$USER_HOME$/.grails/2.1.1/projects/myApp/plugins/resources-1.2/grails-app/taglib" isTestSource="false" />
    </content>
    <content url="file://$USER_HOME$/.grails/2.1.1/projects/myApp/plugins/spring-mobile-0.5.1" />
    <content url="file://$USER_HOME$/.grails/2.1.1/projects/myApp/plugins/spring-security-core-1.2.7.3">
      <sourceFolder url="file://$USER_HOME$/.grails/2.1.1/projects/myApp/plugins/spring-security-core-1.2.7.3/src/java" isTestSource="false" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$USER_HOME$/.grails/2.1.1/projects/myApp/plugins/spring-security-core-1.2.7.3/src/groovy" isTestSource="false" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$USER_HOME$/.grails/2.1.1/projects/myApp/plugins/spring-security-core-1.2.7.3/grails-app/i18n" isTestSource="false" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$USER_HOME$/.grails/2.1.1/projects/myApp/plugins/spring-security-core-1.2.7.3/grails-app/services" isTestSource="false" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$USER_HOME$/.grails/2.1.1/projects/myApp/plugins/spring-security-core-1.2.7.3/grails-app/taglib" isTestSource="false" />
    </content>
    <content url="file://$USER_HOME$/.grails/2.1.1/projects/myApp/plugins/spring-security-ui-0.2">
      <sourceFolder url="file://$USER_HOME$/.grails/2.1.1/projects/myApp/plugins/spring-security-ui-0.2/grails-app/i18n" isTestSource="false" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$USER_HOME$/.grails/2.1.1/projects/myApp/plugins/spring-security-ui-0.2/grails-app/controllers" isTestSource="false" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$USER_HOME$/.grails/2.1.1/projects/myApp/plugins/spring-security-ui-0.2/grails-app/domain" isTestSource="false" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$USER_HOME$/.grails/2.1.1/projects/myApp/plugins/spring-security-ui-0.2/grails-app/services" isTestSource="false" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$USER_HOME$/.grails/2.1.1/projects/myApp/plugins/spring-security-ui-0.2/grails-app/taglib" isTestSource="false" />
    </content>
    <content url="file://$USER_HOME$/.grails/2.1.1/projects/myApp/plugins/svn-1.0.0.M1">
      <sourceFolder url="file://$USER_HOME$/.grails/2.1.1/projects/myApp/plugins/svn-1.0.0.M1/src/groovy" isTestSource="false" />
    </content>
    <content url="file://$USER_HOME$/.grails/2.1.1/projects/myApp/plugins/tomcat-2.1.1" />
    <content url="file://$USER_HOME$/.grails/2.1.1/projects/myApp/plugins/webxml-1.4.1">
      <sourceFolder url="file://$USER_HOME$/.grails/2.1.1/projects/myApp/plugins/webxml-1.4.1/src/groovy" isTestSource="false" />
    </content>
    <orderEntry type="inheritedJdk" />
    <orderEntry type="sourceFolder" forTests="false" />
    <orderEntry type="library" scope="PROVIDED" name="grails-2.1.1" level="application" />
    <orderEntry type="module-library" exported="">
      <library name="Grails User Library (myApp-grailsPlugins)">
        <CLASSES>
          <root url="file://$USER_HOME$/.grails/2.1.1/projects/myApp/plugins/svn-1.0.0.M1/lib" />
          <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/.grails/ivy-cache/org.w3c.css/sac/jars/sac-1.3.jar!/" />
          <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/.grails/ivy-cache/net.sourceforge.cssparser/cssparser/jars/cssparser-0.9.5.jar!/" />
          <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/.grails/ivy-cache/net.sourceforge.nekohtml/nekohtml/jars/nekohtml-1.9.14.jar!/" />
          <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/.grails/ivy-cache/xerces/xercesImpl/jars/xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar!/" />
          <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/.grails/ivy-cache/net.sourceforge.htmlunit/htmlunit-core-js/jars/htmlunit-core-js-2.8.jar!/" />
          <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/.grails/ivy-cache/org.apache.james/apache-mime4j/jars/apache-mime4j-0.6.jar!/" />
          <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/.grails/ivy-cache/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpmime/jars/httpmime-4.0.1.jar!/" />
          <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/.grails/ivy-cache/commons-logging/commons-logging/jars/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar!/" />
          <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/.grails/ivy-cache/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore/jars/httpcore-4.0.1.jar!/" />
          <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/.grails/ivy-cache/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient/jars/httpclient-4.0.1.jar!/" />
          <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/.grails/ivy-cache/xalan/xalan/jars/xalan-2.7.1.jar!/" />
          <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/.grails/ivy-cache/net.sourceforge.htmlunit/htmlunit/jars/htmlunit-2.8.jar!/" />
          <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/.grails/ivy-cache/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-common/jars/selenium-common-2.0a7.jar!/" />
          <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/.grails/ivy-cache/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-htmlunit-driver/jars/selenium-htmlunit-driver-2.0a7.jar!/" />
          <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/.grails/ivy-cache/log4j/log4j/jars/log4j-1.2.14.jar!/" />
          <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/.grails/ivy-cache/net.sourceforge.jexcelapi/jxl/jars/jxl-2.6.12.jar!/" />
          <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/.grails/ivy-cache/org.springframework/spring-test/jars/spring-test-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar!/" />
          <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/.grails/ivy-cache/javax.activation/activation/jars/activation-1.1.jar!/" />
          <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/.grails/ivy-cache/javax.mail/mail/jars/mail-1.4.3.jar!/" />
          <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/.grails/ivy-cache/org.quartz-scheduler/quartz/jars/quartz-2.1.6.jar!/" />
          <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/.grails/ivy-cache/org.springframework.mobile/spring-mobile-device/jars/spring-mobile-device-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar!/" />
          <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/.grails/ivy-cache/org.hibernate/jtidy/jars/jtidy-r8-20060801.jar!/" />
          <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/.grails/ivy-cache/org.hibernate/hibernate-tools/jars/hibernate-tools-3.6.0.CR1.jar!/" />
          <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/.grails/ivy-cache/freemarker/freemarker/jars/freemarker-2.3.8.jar!/" />
          <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/.grails/ivy-cache/org.springframework.security/spring-security-web/jars/spring-security-web-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/" />
          <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/.grails/ivy-cache/org.springframework.security/spring-security-core/jars/spring-security-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/" />
          <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/.grails/ivy-cache/mysql/mysql-connector-java/jars/mysql-connector-java-5.1.20.jar!/" />
          <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/.grails/ivy-cache/org.grails.plugins/spring-mobile/zips/spring-mobile-0.5.1.zip!/" />
          <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/.grails/ivy-cache/org.grails.plugins/jxl/zips/jxl-0.54.zip!/" />
          <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/.grails/ivy-cache/org.grails.plugins/hawk-eventing/zips/hawk-eventing-0.5.1.zip!/" />
          <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/.grails/ivy-cache/org.grails.plugins/svn/zips/svn-1.0.0.M1.zip!/" />
          <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/.grails/ivy-cache/org.grails.plugins/hibernate-hijacker/zips/hibernate-hijacker-0.8.1.zip!/" />
          <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/.grails/ivy-cache/org.grails.plugins/multi-tenant-single-db/zips/multi-tenant-single-db-0.8.3.zip!/" />
          <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/.grails/ivy-cache/org.grails.plugins/mail/zips/mail-1.0.1.zip!/" />
          <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/.grails/ivy-cache/org.grails.plugins/spring-security-ui/zips/spring-security-ui-0.2.zip!/" />
          <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/.grails/ivy-cache/org.grails.plugins/plugin-config/zips/plugin-config-0.1.5.zip!/" />
          <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/.grails/ivy-cache/org.grails.plugins/quartz2/zips/quartz2-2.1.6.2.zip!/" />
          <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/.grails/ivy-cache/org.grails.plugins/db-reverse-engineer/zips/db-reverse-engineer-0.5.zip!/" />
          <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/.grails/ivy-cache/org.grails.plugins/jquery-ui/zips/jquery-ui-1.8.15.zip!/" />
          <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/.grails/ivy-cache/org.grails.plugins/famfamfam/zips/famfamfam-1.0.1.zip!/" />
          <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/.grails/ivy-cache/org.grails.plugins/spring-security-core/zips/spring-security-core-1.2.7.3.zip!/" />
          <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/.grails/ivy-cache/org.grails.plugins/jquery/zips/jquery-1.8.0.zip!/" />
          <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/.grails/ivy-cache/org.grails.plugins/hibernate/zips/hibernate-2.1.1.zip!/" />
          <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/.grails/ivy-cache/org.grails.plugins/grails-json-rest-api-extended/zips/grails-json-rest-api-extended-0.2.6.zip!/" />
          <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/.grails/ivy-cache/org.grails.plugins/tomcat/zips/tomcat-2.1.1.zip!/" />
          <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/.grails/ivy-cache/org.grails.plugins/resources/zips/resources-1.2.zip!/" />
          <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/.grails/ivy-cache/org.grails.plugins/webxml/zips/webxml-1.4.1.zip!/" />
        </CLASSES>
        <JAVADOC />
        <SOURCES />
        <jarDirectory url="file://$USER_HOME$/.grails/2.1.1/projects/myApp/plugins/svn-1.0.0.M1/lib" recursive="false" />
      </library>
    </orderEntry>
  </component>
</module>
```

Comment: I remember reading something in regards to jdk 6 and concurrent hash Map . Issues around slow unsure if leaking mem. Can you not try jdk7 see how that goes?

Comment: If you're looking for paid support OCI can help https://grails.org/support.html

Comment: Graeme, we have emailed and called into OCI, but nobody has contacted us back. Who is a good contact for Grails support? Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

java.util.HashMap is not concurrent, so if you are using it in a Grails service or controller it is probably getting concurrent updates, which will cause a variety of problems, one of which may result in a memory leak when running on a server.

Try using one of the concurrent hash maps instead, such as java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap and see if the problem goes away.